# remove value from for loop

Tags: php, function, loops

Is there any php function that can do this.

```
$k = 6;
for($i=1;$i<$k;$i++)
{
   //exclude number 2,3,4
   echo $i.'<br/>'; //display 1,5,6
}
```

Comment: let's say excluded numbers are in array.

Comment: How geting 1,5,6??? and why 2,3,4 removed.???

Comment: @user2446342 Why do you want to exclude `2,3,4`? What's logic behind?

Comment: I wan't to display unused numbers from $k, excluded numbers are from my database, it means those numbers are used already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a array of numbers you want to exclude,

```
$exclude = array(2,3,4);
$k = 6;
for($i=1;$i<=$k;$i++)
{
  if(!in_array($i,$exclude)){
      echo $i.'<br/>'; //display 1,5,6
  }
}
```

**Note:** I have change your condition from `$i<$k` to `$i<=$k`, as it seems you want `6` to get included in your output.

Comment: works like magic. Thanks sir.

Comment: Glad to help you. Please don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Comment: `array_diff(range(1,6), $exclude);` would be shorter. :D

Comment: 1 and 5 are displayed, no 6 at all.

Comment: @user2446342 - Have you change your condition as I mention in my note ?

Answer (score 0):

What about `continue` statement?

```
$k = 6;
for($i=1;$i<$k;$i++)
{
   //exclude number 2,3,4
   if($i==2 || $i==3 || $i==4) continue;
   echo $i.'<br/>'; //display 1,5,6
}
```